# Android AudioRecorder object wont read from microphone

Tags: java, android, voip

I'm trying to build a voip application on a new android device, i use AudioRecorder to read the microphone but I'm getting no valid results, just white noise.
This happen only on this new device(other work well) and this is probably because this device has `PTT` ability.
Is there some workaround to avoid using AudioRecoder to receive streaming data from the microphone?

Thanks.
supersk.

Answer (score 0):

I did a workaround, I set up mode normal(not in call), right after that i read and change the mode to in call. 
by this i'm getting valid voice and still in the voice call mode.
hope it helps